# How do i set prettier to format my code only on ctrl+s (explicitly) and not by auto-save

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, prettier

I am building website with tailwindcss and in vscode using prettier-tailwindcss-plugin. The thing is that whenever i switch the software generally using alt+enter and then come again to vscode, it automatically formats my classesname and now my cursor remain on same position but my text positions are formatted. for example:- Let's say i am typing mb-4 at column::23 and then switching software back to vscode will place my mb-4 at the starting of classnames assume column::10 but my cursor is in same position i.e. column::23.

I tried disabling format on save but it is also restricting ctrl+s too to not format